# Google Analytic URL based goal not catching everything

Tags: regex, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I have a simple destination based goal triggered by regex match (confirmation page when someone books a trip). Problem is, compared to our crm (on any given day) there is around 20-25% discrepancy.

Here is 3 different types of URL that signaling goal completion :

1. /owner/reservation-confirmation?bv=true&reservationNo=MG3P3
2. /owner/reservation-confirmation?bv=true&type=Future&reservationNo=MG4GX
3. /owner/reservation-confirmation?type=Future&reservationNo=MG225

And Goal destination Regex:

(/owner/reservation-confirmation\?bv=true&type=Future&reservationNo=.* )|(/owner/reservation-confirmation\?type=Future&reservationNo=.* )|(/owner/reservation-confirmation\?bv=true&reservationNo=.* )

For some reason, GA missed creating a completed goal for URL's like:

/owner/reservation-confirmation?type=Future&reservationNo=MG4J0

(URL above is in GA under "site content/all pages)

Goal setup :
[image]

Any idea why is this happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The space at the end of each group appears to be breaking this. The following (also with correct escape characters for the forward slashes) works fine:

`(\/owner\/reservation-confirmation\?bv=true&type=Future&reservationNo=.*)|(\/owner\/reservation-confirmation\?type=Future&reservationNo=.*)|(\/owner\/reservation-confirmation\?bv=true&reservationNo=.*)`

regex101.com working example [here](https://regex101.com/r/7qYTUS/1).

Comment: Thank you, Jamie. For some reason, copypaste added extra spaces. Anyhow, I tested regex on uncaught URL and worked but GA failed to register goal.

Comment: Is the middle segment of your regex exactly like this? `(\/owner\/reservation-confirmation\?type=Future&reservationNo=.*)` 

Be sure to include the escape characters, since slashes and question marks have special meaning in regex.

Comment: Correct. I am escaping all special characters ( / and ?). But google analytics not firing a goal completion. two seemingly same url's one was registered as goal one not.
Registered a goal 
:/owner/reservation-confirmation?type=Future&reservationNo=MG225

URL in GA but no goal registered:
/owner/reservation-confirmation?type=Future&reservationNo=MG225

Added my goal setup image into the original post.